# Are my DNF and CNF for $A \land (A \lor C) \implies (C \lor B)$ correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

Is this calucation of DNF and CNF for the formula $A \land (A \lor C) \implies (C \lor B)$ correct?
$$
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
    \hline
      \text{Given:}
    &  A \land (A \lor C) \implies (C \lor B)
    \\
    \hline
       {}
    &  (\neg(A \land (A \lor C)) \lor (C \lor B))
    \\
    \hline
       {}
    &  (\neg A \lor \neg(A \lor C) \lor (C \lor B))
    \\
    \hline
       {}
    &  (\neg A \lor (\neg A \land \neg C) \lor (C \vee B))
    \\
    \hline
       \text{DNF:}
    &  \neg A \lor (\neg A \land \neg C) \lor C \lor B
    \\
    \hline
       {}
    &  \neg A \lor (C \lor B)
    \\
    \hline
       \text{DNF and CNF:}
    &  \neg A \lor C \lor B
    \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
$$
(Original picture of the calculation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av39r.png).)

When I got the DNF, I applied the absorption rule in order to get DNF/CNF.

Comment: Thanks for your correction @Jendrik Stelzner - did you also check the calculations?

Comment: It has been some time since I’ve dealt with DNF/CNF, but your calculations seem correct to me. But I would prefer it if someone with more expertise would post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The calculus is correct.   You can also check the final answer to be sure it is an equivalence.

If $A$ is false, $A\wedge(A\vee C)\to(C\vee B)$ is true, as is the case when either $C$ or $B$ is true.   So if and only if $\neg A\vee B\vee C$ do we have the implication.

---

Note also an easier route would have been to apply absorption equivalence first, then implication equivalence: $A\wedge(A\vee C)\to(C\vee B)\\\equiv A\to (C\vee B)\\\equiv \neg A\vee C\vee B$